# is it necessary to set up all banking account info in the iphone dev account before submitting a paid app

Tags: iphone

I just wanted to know if its necessary to set up all the banking info before proceeding with submission of the actual paid app for the binary.

Thanks and Regards,
Harikant Jammi

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to complete banking info before submitting a paid app binary.  But you won't get paid until you set up banking info.